# Nuclear shapes and deformation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, nuclear-physics

How do the experimentally measured multipole moments (static or transition) give information about the deformed nuclear shape? Since deformation is not directly observable, the only information we get is via the multipole moments, which tell us whether is is a quadrupole deformation or hexadecapole. How are these moments related to the deformation? Are they obtained just from the multipole expansion of the charge densities?

Moreover, how do we measure the 'moments' of charge density? When density is measured, what classifies it into its quadrupole, octupole etc moments.?